# Xcode create bundle with cpp files

Tags: c++, xcode, cocoa

I'm trying to create a bundle application using Xcode 10.3. 
The main code is going to live inside a C++ file, which I added to the bundle project, and I also need to use some Cocoa related stuff.
and here is the catch, anytime I include

```
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

I immediately get like 20 errors [image]

which are rather strange. Is there anything else to be added or set in Xcode so I can include Cocoa headers inside a CPP file?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution was easier than expected, you just have to change the compilation type for the cpp file from `C++ Source` to `Objective-C++ Source` and then everything compiles as needed.

Comment: Alternatively you can also name the file with the `.mm` extension and it will be treated as `Objective-C++ Source`